# JavaScript onchange to submit form to different location

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get this working with the `onchange` event. The alert triggers but I need the form submitting.

```
<script>
    function validatelink3(returnpartid){
        alert("test");
        var theform = document.partsform;
        theform.action="process_quickedited.asp?returnpartid="+returnpartid;
    }
</script>

<form id="partsform" name="partsform" method="post" action="process_quickedited.asp?returnpartid=undefined">

    <select name="STOCKACTION<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>" id="STOCKACTION<%=objRst.fields    ("returnpartid")%>" onchange="validatelink3(<%=objRst.fields("returnpartid")%>)">
        <option value="<%response.write objRst.fields("stockaction")%>" selected="selected"><%response.write objRst.fields("stockaction")%></option>
        <option value="Return To Supplier">Return To Supplier</option>
        <option value="Stock">Stock</option>
        <option value="Scrap">Scrap</option>
        <option value="Quarantine">Quarantine</option>
        <option value="Test">Test</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly?

Comment: use window.location instead

Comment: Hi Amy, I want to submit a form called partsform to the location ="process_quickedited.asp?returnpartid="+returnpartid; - I don't think I can use window.location as this will not submit the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `validatelink3()` to submit the form, you can use the [`HTMLFormElement.submit`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767676) method:

```
function validatelink3(returnpartid){
    alert("test");
    var theform = document.partsform;
    theform.action="process_quickedited.asp?returnpartid="+returnpartid;
    theform.submit();
}
```

Comment: Perffect, thank you. I was almost there, had tried theform.submit but without the brackets which didn't work. This works perfectly.